# Compare / Search Text Files Line by Line Search for particular words

Tags: c#, text, compare

Hy my Friends :)

So i have a litte problem, i have a Text File with following content 
This i from an email Script.

```
Email: usera@hotmail.com
Status: done
Lang: En
Date: 05-10-2012
--------------------------------
Email: userb@hotmail.com
Status: waiting
Lang: En
Date: 05-10-2012
```

Ok now i will read this text file and write Only the Email and Status in a Richtextbox.
Like this

```
usera@hotmail.com;done
userb@hotmail.com;waiting
```

Only the status and the email should be in the Richtextbox sepperated with the ";" 
The other text ( Lang , Date) can be Ignored.

My idea was Read the text file in a stream and try with a Foreach fuc to find "Email" and "Status" then print in the Richbox, but i think this is not a good way to do this.
So i ask you what is the best way to make this possible?

my test code

```
string[] filea = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
        foreach (var s in filea)
        {
            if (s.Contains("Email"))
            {

              richTextBox1.AppendText(s + Environment.NewLine);
           }

        }
```

but how i get in there the "Status" too?
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the requested output, you'll need to split each line and then grab just the part you want:

```
string[] filea = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
foreach (var s in filea)
{
    string[] parts = s.Split(':');

    if (parts.Length == 2)
    {
        if (parts[0].Contains("Email"))
            richTextBox1.AppendText(parts[1].Trim());

        if (parts[0].Contains("Status"))
            richTextBox1.AppendText(":" + parts[1].Trim() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome how fast we get here help! , This soulution works perfekt, and now i just learned a bit again :) thank you